# Why do I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException error in cursor even though column rows are correct?

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have a dictionary app which stores a word with the meaning, type (English,Chinese,Japanese etc) and favorite status (whether it's a favorite word). On 1 of my menu items, there's this item called sort. When I click on it, I am expecting the words in my main page to be sorted in ascending order but instead I got this error in *ListFragment.java*: **'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.'**. There's nothing wrong with my database.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary.db.WordsDataSource;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFragment.OnContactSelectedInterface/*,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener*/ {

    protected WordsDataSource myDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDataSource = new WordsDataSource(this);

        this.setTitle("PD");
        //The code here decides whether to create the fragment because it can be destroyed by the Android system
        //when it reclaims memory
        ListFragment savedFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WORDS_FRAGMENT");
        if (savedFragment == null) {
            ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean("isFavourite", false);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeHolder, fragment, "WORDS_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //The code here is required because when I save the data and navigate back
        //I need my applicationn logic to refresh the fragement content to reflect the changes
        //to avoid the list interface listing the old data.
        super.onResume();
        ListFragment savedFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WORDS_FRAGMENT");
        if (savedFragment != null) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(savedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.attach(savedFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListContactSelected(int index) {
        //When tap on a row display word, this logic here will start collecting the
        //id which is tied to the data and navigate the user to another Activity
        //and at the same time pass the id over.
        //   Toast.makeText(this, "PUMPKINNNNNN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); for testing if tap detected
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WordsDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("WordId", index);//index variable name may not be suitable here
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        String itemTitle = item.getTitle().toString();
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.favourite) {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "GER" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Go to favorite action choice detected
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FavouriteActivity.class));
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Add) {
            //   Toast.makeText(this, "EEEEYEERR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Go to add word action choice detected
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddWordsActivity.class));
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.sort) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean("isSortByAsc", true);

            ListFragment savedFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WORDS_FRAGMENT");

            if (savedFragment != null) {
                savedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.detach(savedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.attach(savedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }  
        }
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
}
```

**ListFragment.java**

```
 package mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary.db.WordsDataSource;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    protected WordsDataSource mDataSource;
    private boolean isFavourite;
    private boolean isSortByAsc;

    public interface OnContactSelectedInterface {

        void onListContactSelected(int index);

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        OnContactSelectedInterface listener = (OnContactSelectedInterface) getActivity();

        isFavourite = getArguments().getBoolean("isFavourite");
        isSortByAsc = getArguments().getBoolean("isSortByAsc");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container,false);

        //-------------------
        //The rest of the code below is to read all or favorite word data
        //and fill up the ArrayList variable.
        mDataSource = new WordsDataSource(getContext());
        mDataSource.open();
        Cursor cursor;
        if(isFavourite){
             cursor = mDataSource.selectFavouriteWords();
        }
      else if (isSortByAsc){

            cursor = mDataSource.sortWords();
        }

        else{
             cursor = mDataSource.selectAllWords();
    }

        ArrayList<Words> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){


            boolean tempFav = true;//The database uses 0 and 1 to represent true or false
            //Therefore I used this tempFav so that my logic here can store true or false
            //during the getString() call
            //Error occurs here
            if (cursor.getInt(4) != 0) {
                tempFav = false;
            }


            Words tempWords =new Words(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),tempFav);
            tempWords.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            wordsList.add(tempWords);
            //Log.d("MY Activity", "onCreateView: "+  tempWords.getId()+" " + tempWords.getWord()+" " +tempWords.getMeaning()+" "+ tempWords.getType()+" "+  cursor.getInt(4));
            Log.d("MY Activity", "cursor: "+  cursor.getInt(0)+ " "+cursor.getString(1)+" " + cursor.getString(2)+" "+cursor.getString(3)+" " + cursor.getInt(4));
            //Column 0 is id, column 1 is word, column 2 is meaning, column 3 is type, column 4 is favorite status(0 for true and 1 for false)
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        mDataSource.close();
        //-----------------------
        //After the ArrayList variable is filled with data,
        //create a listAdapter type object
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        //Creating a ListAdapter object and at the same time pass in a "walkie-talkie" so that it can
        //yell out if any related events happening and also the ArrayList of contect information
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(listener, wordsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);//Start using it
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return view;
    }


}
```

**WordsDataSource.java**

```
    package mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary.db;
//insert update delete
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary.Words;

public class WordsDataSource {

        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
        private WordsHelper mWordsHelper;
        private Context mContext;

    public WordsDataSource(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mWordsHelper = new WordsHelper(mContext);
    }

    //open data base
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = mWordsHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }
    //close
    public void close() {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
    //insert
    public void insertWords(Words words) {
        mDatabase.beginTransaction();
        try{
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD, words.getWord());
            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_MEANING, words.getMeaning());
            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_TYPE, words.getType());

            int fav = 0;
            if (!words.isFavourite()) {
                fav = 1;
            }
            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITE, fav);
            mDatabase.insert(WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS, null, values);

            mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            mDatabase.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    //sort
    public Cursor sortWords (){
        String[] wordname = new String[]{ WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD };
        Cursor cursor= mDatabase.query(WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,wordname , null, null, null, null, WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD+" ASC");

return cursor;
    }

    //select
    public Cursor selectAllWords(){
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from " + WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor selectOneWord(int Id){
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from " + WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS+" where "
                + WordsHelper.COLUMN_ID+" = " + Id, null);
        return cursor;
    }
    public Cursor selectFavouriteWords() {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from " + WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS+" where "
                + WordsHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITE+" = 0" , null);
        return cursor;
    }
    //update
    public boolean updateWords(int id, String word, String meaning,String type, boolean fav){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        int success = -1;

        values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD, word);
        values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_MEANING, meaning);
        values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_TYPE, type);

        int favDigit = 0;
        if(!fav){
            favDigit = 1;
        }


        values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITE, favDigit);


        success =  mDatabase.update(
                WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,
                values,
                WordsHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id,
                null

        );
        if(success != -1 && success != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean setFavourite (int id, boolean fav) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        int success = -1;
        int favDigit = 0;
        if(!fav){
            favDigit = 1;
        }
        values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITE, favDigit);
        success =  mDatabase.update(
                WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,
                values,
                WordsHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id,
                null

        );
        if(success != -1 && success != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean updateWords(int id, String word, String meaning,String type){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        int success = -1;
        if(word != null ){
            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_WORD, word);
        }

        if(meaning != null ){
            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_MEANING, meaning);
        }

        if(type != null ){
            values.put(WordsHelper.COLUMN_TYPE, type);
        }


        success =  mDatabase.update(
                WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,
                values,
                WordsHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id,
                null

        );
        if(success != -1 && success != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    //delete
    public boolean deleteWords(int id) {
        int success = -1;
        success = mDatabase.delete(
                WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,
                WordsHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id,
                null
        );
        if(success != -1 && success !=0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean deleteWords() {
        int success = -1;
        success = mDatabase.delete(
                WordsHelper.TABLE_WORDS,
                null,
                null
        );
        if(success != -1 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**WordsHelper.java**

```
    package mapp.com.sg.pocketdictionary.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
//Helps make all code in WordsDataSource neater, readable and maintainable.

public class WordsHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_WORDS ="WORDS";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_WORD = "WORD";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEANING = "MEANING";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "TYPE";
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVOURITE = "FAVOURITE";



    private static final String DB_NAME = "words.db";
    private static final int DB_VER = 1;
    private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_WORDS+
            " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            ", " + COLUMN_WORD + " TEXT, "  +
            COLUMN_MEANING + " TEXT,"+
            COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_FAVOURITE +" INTEGER)";


    public WordsHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: post the `WordsDataSourc` code so we can see the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to access

```
 int value=cursor.getInt(4)
```

and it have null value or out of rang of integer it will throw exception.

for such case try below code

```
if ( !cursor.isNull( columnIndex ) )
 {
 value = cursor.getInt( columnIndex );
 }
 else
 {
 value=0; //default value
 }
```

For debugging purpose first check the value of cursor using below code

```
Log.d("CursorObject", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor))
```

Comment: in my case, would it be something like this:   `int value=cursor.getInt(4);

            if ( !cursor.isNull(4) )
                {
                    value = cursor.getInt(4 );
                }

                else
                {
                    value=0; //default value
                }`Because I don't think this works.

Comment: No,it's like `if ( !cursor.isNull(4) ) { value = cursor.getInt(4 ); } else { value=0; //default value }`.There is no need to `int value=cursor.getInt(4);` before the if statment

Comment: i have updated the code for check the value of cusrsor

Comment: oh my gosh, thank you! Thanks to the debugging, I finally realised my problem. Instead of using all columns, I only used 1 column from my database.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to read the data, you need to get `ReadableDatabase` but your open always gets `WritableDatabase`as in

**Main code**

```
  mDataSource = new WordsDataSource(getContext());
            mDataSource.openforRead(); // <-- will return readable database
            Cursor cursor;
            if(isFavourite){
                 cursor = mDataSource.selectFavouriteWords();
            }
          else if (isSortByAsc){

                cursor = mDataSource.sortWords();
            }

            else{
                 cursor = mDataSource.selectAllWords();
        }
          ArrayList<Words> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){


            boolean tempFav = true;//The database uses 0 and 1 to represent true or false
            //Therefore I used this tempFav so that my logic here can store true or false
            //during the getString() call
            //Error occurs here
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(WordsHelper.COLUMN_FAVOURITE)) != 0) {
                tempFav = false;
            }


            Words tempWords =new Words(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),tempFav);
            tempWords.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            wordsList.add(tempWords);
            //Log.d("MY Activity", "onCreateView: "+  tempWords.getId()+" " + tempWords.getWord()+" " +tempWords.getMeaning()+" "+ tempWords.getType()+" "+  cursor.getInt(4));
            Log.d("MY Activity", "cursor: "+  cursor.getInt(0)+ " "+cursor.getString(1)+" " + cursor.getString(2)+" "+cursor.getString(3)+" " + cursor.getInt(4));
            //Column 0 is id, column 1 is word, column 2 is meaning, column 3 is type, column 4 is favorite status(0 for true and 1 for false)
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
```

Add below method to `WordsDataSource`

```
  public void openForRead() throws SQLException {
            mDatabase = mWordsHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     }
```

Comment: try reinstalling app and use `getColumnIndex(<columnname>)` instead hardcoding index as in updated answer

Comment: I get this error instead: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."